# How start different activity (and recover state) if service is running?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I've got a fairly complete location tracking app, but one problem is still bugging me. When launched, the app needs to display the second activity if the tracking service is currently running.

- I have 2 activities (LoginActivity and MainActivity) and 2 services (LocationService and ReportingService - both run in their own processes).
- When the app is tracking location, the 2 services must remain alive, but MainActivity can be killed.
- LocationService creates an unremovable notification to ensure the user knows they're being tracked. When the user taps the notification, it will restart/create MainActivity - the intent has extras containing all the relevant data that MainActivity needs (the Accounts and Assets they have access to, and which ones are selected).

However, if the app is tracking and MainActivity has been killed and then the user opens the app via the regular launcher icon, they're taken to LoginActivity. LoginActivity is the typical entry point for the app, as defined in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

---

**How can I have MainActivity be used as an alternate entry point if LocationService is currently tracking? How should it recover its previous state data?**

- Do I need to add some special logic to LoginActivity's onCreate() to check the running services and then immediately launch MainActivity?
- If I do something like that, I then have another problem: there would be no state data for MainActivity. Is there a way to access the notification's intent if the user doesn't open it via the notification?
- MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState() saves the state data to a bundle, but I think that that's gone after the activity is killed, isn't it?
- I have considered saving the state data directly to SharedPreferences, but this feels undesirably hacky. My "thing" objects all implement Parcelable so they can be put in bundles and intent extras, but you can't put Parcelables in SharedPreferences. I could hack around this by JSONifying them, but the JSON representations of the objects were only intended for communicating with the RESTful servers, so they don't include some app-specific data. I dislike dirty hacks so I'd rather do this the *right* way.

---

**Steps I think would be required:**

1. When tracking starts, MainActivity stores the DB IDs of the Accounts and Assets in SharedPreferences
2. When LoginActivity is created, check whether LocationService is running
3. If so, launch MainActivity with a special "restore from SharedPreferences" extra
4. MainActivity.onCreate() displays a loading dialog and gets the DB IDs from SharedPreferences
5. Broadcast to ReportingService that we need to fetch the objects corresponding to the DB IDs
6. Listen for response, then update the UI and cancel the loading dialog

---

**What's the best way to approach these problems?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `LoginActivity.onCreate()` you should check to see if the tracking services are running and if so, immediately forward the user to `MainActivity`. You want to do this as if the user clicked on the `Notification`, so that you can use the extras in the `PendingIntent` that you have stored in the `Notification`. No problem.

In `LoginActivity.onCreate()` do this:

```
// Find the PendingIntent that is stored in the Notification
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
// Add any ACTION or DATA or flags that you added when you created the
//  Intent and PendingIntent when you created the Notification

// Now get the `PendingIntent` that is stored in the notification
//  (make sure you use the same "requestCode" as you did when creating
//  the PendingIntent that you stored in the Notification)
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
    requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
// Now start MainActivity with the Intent wrapped in the PendingIntent
//  (it contains the extras)
pendingIntent.send();
// Finish LoginActivity (if you usually do that when you launch MainActivity)
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem thanks to [David Wasser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200716/how-start-different-activity-and-recover-state-if-service-is-running/46203057#46203057)'s helpful guidance. I've included everything that's required in this answer to help anyone else who encounters this problem.

---

As soon as LoginActivity is created, it (indirectly) checks whether we're tracking:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // It's possible that we're already tracking. If so, we want to skip LoginActivity and start MainActivity.
    if(Utilities.doesTrackingPendingIntentExist(this))
    {
        if(Utilities.isLocationServiceRunning(this))
        {
            recreateMainActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "TRACKING? PendingIntent exists, but LocationService isn't running.");
            Utilities.deleteTrackingPendingIntent(this);
        }
    }

    // LocationService wasn't running, so we can display the login screen and proceed as normal
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__login);
    ...
```

---

If so, it grabs the PendingIntent that LocationService had created for the notification and it uses it to start MainActivity.

```
private void recreateMainActivity()
{
    // This intent is an abstract description of what we want to accomplish: starting MainActivity
    Intent intentToStartMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    // Get the PendingIntent that's stored in the notification (using the "requestCode" that LocationService used
    // when it created the PendingIntent)
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
    (
        this, LocationService.NOTIFICATION_ID, intentToStartMainActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
    );

    try
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "LocationService is running. Attempting to recreate MainActivity!");

        // Now start MainActivity with the Intent wrapped in the PendingIntent (which also contains the required data in extras)
        pendingIntent.send();
        finish();
    }
    catch(PendingIntent.CanceledException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "It seems that our PendingIntent was cancelled. Hmmm....", e);
    }
}
```

---

Here's the Utilities function we use to determine whether we're tracking. It checks whether a matching PendingIntent already exists based on the ID and the Intent. If the PendingIntent is null, that means no match was found, so we take that to mean that the notification doesn't exist and we aren't tracking. In API 23+, you can directly check if a notification exists, which would be slightly safer than this (as the PendingNotification could continue to exist after the notification is gone if the service is unexpectedly killed).

```
public static boolean doesTrackingPendingIntentExist(Context context)
{
    Intent intentToStartMainActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // Get the PendingIntent that's stored in the notification (using the "requestCode" that LocationService used
    // when it created the PendingIntent)
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
    (
        context, LocationService.NOTIFICATION_ID, intentToStartMainActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
    );

    if(pendingIntent == null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "TRACKING? No matching PendingIntent found. LocationService probably isn't running.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "TRACKING? A matching PendingIntent was found. LocationService seems to be running.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

An alternate method that checks whether service is running by looping through all running services looking for a name match. Since my LocationService doesn't always die immediately after onDestroy(), this alone isn't a perfectly reliable way to check whether we're tracking. It can be combined with the other method for a more certain determination of tracking status.

```
public static boolean isLocationServiceRunning(Context context)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "TRACKING? Reviewing all services to see if LocationService is running.");

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Go through every service until we find LocationService
    for(ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "TRACKING?    service.getClassName() = " + service.service.getClassName());

        if(LocationService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "TRACKING? LocationService is running!");
            return true;
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "TRACKING? LocationService is NOT running.");
    return false;
}
```

---

**Caution:**
It's very important that LocationService cancels the PendingIntent when it's done tracking or this won't work. Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that LocationService.onDestroy() will be called by the OS. Android could kill it without calling that. It runs with foreground priority, so it's unlikely to be unexpectedly killed, but it could result in the PendingIntent existing while you're not tracking.

Combining both of those utility functions is the safest way to determine whether we're tracking.

**Side note:**
I tried using a static volatile boolean to track the tracking state in LocationService, but the different processes <s>seemed to use different ClassLoaders</s> have their own memory spaces (thanks David). If your code is all in the same process, that approach may work for you.

Comment: Different OS processes have completely different memory spaces and their own VM's, not just different class loaders.  You cannot share data using `static` variables between OS processes.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. When first looking into this, I glossed over mentions of threads without thinking of the implications of having my services running in different processes.

Volatile variables may be enough for multi-threaded programs, although there are cases where synchronized variables are required, as explained here (for anyone who wants to learn more):

[What is the difference between a process and a thread in Java?](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/01/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread-in-java/)

(As David pointed out, neither of those apply here)